# How to catch all signals from child processes, while using poll for multiple file descriptors?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, signal-handling, multiple-processes

So I have this assignment and they tell me that I have to create a process tree (with **number_of_children** forks), send some messages from bottom level workers to the root of the process tree and finally before the workers exit, they must send a SIGUSR1 signal to root. After some (irrelevant to my problem) printing, has to print the number of signals received.

Firstly I set the signal handler, calling this routine (which I found online and it works pretty fine I think):

```
void set_signal_handler(int signo, void (*handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void *)) {
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    // set up signal handler 
    if (sigaction(signo, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Then I use a for loop create a unnamed pipe array for each child, then fork the children and at the end call a routine that is monitoring the file descriptors so that I can read in a non-blocking manner. The logic of polling is the following:

```
while(open_files>0) {
    int retval = poll(fds, number_of_children, 0);

    // try to read only if poll does not fail
    if (retval > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_children; i++){
            reading from children
        }
    }
}
```

And in this way I read everything write (although poll gets interrupted sometimes from signals) and there is no problem in reading.

The **actual problem** is that when I print the SIGUSR1 signals the root received, **I do not get consistent values**. Among several runs for, let's say 3 child processes per process node, I get values from 3 to 9(which is correct). Is there any safer method to handle signals and not dumb them.

> **Note** : After some research I know that I can't make signals of the same type be pending (I tried sending signals with sigqueue). I also tried ignoring the signals during poll and re-set the handler at the end  of polling but, of course, it did not work since the signals were already dumbed. I also checked out a relative stack post, and declared my signal_counter as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, still it is not consistent.

Comment: Real-time signals are queued, but SIGUSR1 isn't a real-time signal. If, during the time that SIGUSR1 is held (either implicitly while its handler is running, or by calling `sigprocmask`), two or more instances of the signal are received, they'll be coalesced into one. If your assignment says you need to count the number of SIGUSR1 signals received, I don't believe it's possible. You can get the equivalent by having each process write a byte to a shared pipe prior to sending the signal and then having the target process read from the pipe and tally them up. Can you show us the full assigment?

Comment: Are you sure that observing the inconsistency in the number of signals handled is not intended as part of the assignment?  Because it seems to me that the issue you're struggling with is exactly one that would bear some attention in a course that covers signal handling.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think that you might be right about that. I was doing a little more research and I came to the same conclusion. It's not possible to catch all the usr1 signals the workers send, so I will keep it as I have it since the point of the project is to see how unreliable signals are.